# How to execute postgres' sql queries from batch file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to execute SQL from batch file.
I am executing following to connect to Postgres and select data from table

```
C:/pgsql/bin/psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME% 
select * from test;
```

I am able to connect to database, however I'm getting the error

> 'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Has anyone faced such issue?

This is one of the query i am trying, something similar works in shell script, (please ignore syntax error in the query if there are any)

```
copy testdata (col1,col2,col3) from '%filepath%/%csv_file%' with csv;
```

Comment: As mentioned below, try adding -c parameter before the sql command

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could pipe it into psql

```
(
echo select * from test;
) | C:/pgsql/bin/psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
```

When closing parenthesis are part of the SQL query they have to be escaped with three carets.

```
( 
echo insert into testconfig(testid,scenarioid,testname ^^^) values( 1,1,'asdf'^^^);
) | psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%
```

Comment: this is the current query I'm trying, `( echo insert into testconfig(testid,scenarioid,testname) values( 1,1,'asdf'); ) | psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME%` and i'm getting `value( was unexpected at this time.` 
any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, see my second sample. you need three carets per closing parenthesis. `...(name1 ^^^) values(value1 ^^^)`

Comment: how can i save the output in csv file in windows ??

Comment: `( 
echo SELECT * FROM docteur;
) | C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d docarriv_db`
Here is an example ( windows 10, PostgreSQL 9.6) according to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-f` parameter to pass the batch file name

```
C:/pgsql/bin/psql -h %DB_HOST% -p 5432 -U %DB_USER% -d %DB_NAME% -f 'sql_batch_file.sql'
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

> -f filename
>
> --file=filename
>
> Use the file filename as the source of commands instead of reading commands interactively. After the file is processed, psql terminates. This is in many ways equivalent to the meta-command \i.
>
> If filename is - (hyphen), then standard input is read until an EOF indication or \q meta-command. Note however that Readline is not used in this case (much as if -n had been specified).

Comment: queries that that needs to be executed have batch variables in them as data. i am not very sure if external sql file can be used with this.

Comment: @ketub: Post a sample of the queries you want to execute in the question.

Comment: `copy testdata (col1,col2,col3) from '%filepath%/%csv_file%' with csv;`
This is one of the query i am trying, something similar works in shell script, (please ignore syntax error in the query if there are any)

Answer (score 2):

if running on Linux, this is what worked for me (need to update values below with your user, db name etc)

```
psql "host=YOUR_HOST port=YOUR_PORT dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME user=YOUR_USER_NAME password=YOUR_PASSWORD" -f "fully_qualified_path_to_your_script.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put the query on separate line, batch interpreter will assume it's another command instead of a query for psql. I believe you will need to quote it as well.

Comment: in Shell Script i used 
`<< EOF`
`sql queries`
`sql queries`
`sql queries`
`EOF`
does batch has something on similar grounds?

Comment: @ketub the "HereDoc" `<< EOF` does not work on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Spidey:

> 1] if you are passing the file with the sql use -f or --file parameter

When you want to execute several commands the best way to do that is to add parameter -f, and after that just type path to your file without any " or ' marks (relative paths works also):

```
psql -h %host% -p 5432 -U %user% -d %dbname% -f ..\..\folder\Data.txt
```

It also works in .NET Core. I need it to add basic data to my database after migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html)

1] if you are passing the file with the sql use `-f` or `--file` parameter
2] if you are passing individual command use `-c` or `--command` parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying the shell script

`psql postgresql://$username:$password@$host/$database < /app/sql_script/script.sql`